Next js 14 Typescript generate data booking and pass from link url
I'm making a booking web app with Next JS 14 Typescript, I want to create a URL link like in the picture.
how to create a URL link followed by confidential booking data?, where the booking data is obtained from the previous page
Do you normally use JWT or Bcrypt?, or is there a certain format or library
I've tried using bcrypt to be like this /booking/$2b$10$2lBPDK1pQNrnY6hFCz.82.4qiZW6tZfWPZIvZSrJfB.5y6fIZxUHa, but it doesn't seem normal, so what should I do?

Bcrypt is a one-way hashing function, so it’s not something you could use if you need to reverse the encryption and recover the original data. I think the goals could be stated more clearly in the question. Who are you trying to keep the parameters confidential from?
